# Dropzone.js cannot find Dropzone reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, dropzone.js

```js
// Type definitions for Dropzone 4.3.0
// Project: http://www.dropzonejs.com/
// Definitions by: Natan Vivo <https://github.com/nvivo>, Andy Hawkins <https://github.com/a904guy/,http://a904guy.com/,http://www.bmbsqd.com>, Vasya Aksyonov <https://github.com/outring>, Simon Huber <https://github.com/renuo>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts"/>

interface DropzoneResizeInfo {
 srcX?:number;
 srcY?:number;
 trgX?:number;
 trgY?:number;
 srcWidth?:number;
 srcHeight?:number;
 trgWidth?:number;
 trgHeight?:number;
 optWidth?:number;
 optHeight?:number;
}

interface DropzoneFile extends File {
 previewElement: HTMLElement;
 previewTemplate: HTMLElement;
 previewsContainer: HTMLElement;
 status: string;
 accepted: boolean;
}

interface DropzoneOptions {
 url?: string;
 method?: string;
 withCredentials?: boolean;
 parallelUploads?: number;
 uploadMultiple?: boolean;
 maxFilesize?: number;
 paramName?: string;
 createImageThumbnails?: boolean;
 maxThumbnailFilesize?: number;
 thumbnailWidth?: number;
 thumbnailHeight?: number;
 filesizeBase?: number;
 maxFiles?: number;
 params?: {};
 headers?: {};
 clickable?: boolean|string|HTMLElement|(string|HTMLElement)[];
 ignoreHiddenFiles?: boolean;
 acceptedFiles?: string;
 renameFilename?(name:string): string;
 autoProcessQueue?: boolean;
 autoQueue?: boolean;
 addRemoveLinks?: boolean;
 previewsContainer?: boolean|string|HTMLElement;
 hiddenInputContainer?: HTMLElement;
 capture?: string;

 dictDefaultMessage?: string;
 dictFallbackMessage?: string;
 dictFallbackText?: string;
 dictFileTooBig?: string;
 dictInvalidFileType?: string;
 dictResponseError?: string;
 dictCancelUpload?: string;
 dictCancelUploadConfirmation?: string;
 dictRemoveFile?: string;
 dictRemoveFileConfirmation?: string;
 dictMaxFilesExceeded?: string;

 accept?(file:DropzoneFile, done:(error?:string|Error) => void):void;
 init?():void;
 forceFallback?: boolean;
 fallback?():void;
 resize?(file:DropzoneFile):DropzoneResizeInfo;

 drop?(e:DragEvent):void;
 dragstart?(e:DragEvent):void;
 dragend?(e:DragEvent):void;
 dragenter?(e:DragEvent):void;
 dragover?(e:DragEvent):void;
 dragleave?(e:DragEvent):void;
 paste?(e:DragEvent):void;

 reset?():void;

 addedfile?(file:DropzoneFile):void;
 addedfiles?(files:DropzoneFile[]):void;
 removedfile?(file:DropzoneFile):void;
 thumbnail?(file:DropzoneFile, dataUrl:string):void;

 error?(file:DropzoneFile, message:string|Error, xhr:XMLHttpRequest):void;
 errormultiple?(files:DropzoneFile[], message:string|Error, xhr:XMLHttpRequest):void;

 processing?(file:DropzoneFile):void;
 processingmultiple?(files:DropzoneFile[]):void;

 uploadprogress?(file:DropzoneFile, progress:number, bytesSent:number):void;
 totaluploadprogress?(totalProgress:number, totalBytes:number, totalBytesSent:number):void;

 sending?(file:DropzoneFile, xhr:XMLHttpRequest, formData:FormData):void;
 sendingmultiple?(files:DropzoneFile[], xhr:XMLHttpRequest, formData:FormData):void;

 success?(file: DropzoneFile, response: Object|string): void;
 successmultiple?(files:DropzoneFile[], responseText:string):void;

 canceled?(file:DropzoneFile):void;
 canceledmultiple?(file:DropzoneFile[]):void;

 complete?(file:DropzoneFile):void;
 completemultiple?(file:DropzoneFile[]):void;

 maxfilesexceeded?(file:DropzoneFile):void;
 maxfilesreached?(files:DropzoneFile[]):void;
 queuecomplete?():void;

 previewTemplate?: string;
}

declare class Dropzone {
 constructor(container:string|HTMLElement, options?:DropzoneOptions);

 static autoDiscover:boolean;
 static options:any;
 static confirm:(question:string, accepted:() => void, rejected?:() => void) => void;

 static ADDED:string;
 static QUEUED:string;
 static ACCEPTED:string;
 static UPLOADING:string;
 static PROCESSING:string;
 static CANCELED:string;
 static ERROR:string;
 static SUCCESS:string;

 files:DropzoneFile[];

 enable():void;

 disable():void;

 destroy():Dropzone;

 addFile(file:DropzoneFile):void;

 removeFile(file:DropzoneFile):void;

 removeAllFiles(cancelIfNecessary?:boolean):void;

 processQueue():void;

 cancelUpload(file:DropzoneFile):void;

 processFiles(files:DropzoneFile[]):void;

 processFile(file:DropzoneFile):void;

 uploadFile(file:DropzoneFile):void;

 getAcceptedFiles():DropzoneFile[];

 getRejectedFiles():DropzoneFile[];

 getQueuedFiles():DropzoneFile[];

 getUploadingFiles():DropzoneFile[];

 accept(file:DropzoneFile, done:(error?:string|Error) => void):void;

 getActiveFiles():DropzoneFile[];

 getFilesWithStatus(status:string):DropzoneFile[];

 enqueueFile(file:DropzoneFile):void;

 enqueueFiles(file:DropzoneFile[]):void;

 createThumbnail(file:DropzoneFile, callback?:(...args:any[]) => void):any;

 createThumbnailFromUrl(file:DropzoneFile, url:string, callback?:(...args:any[]) => void):any;

 on(eventName:string, callback:(...args:any[]) => void):Dropzone;

 off(eventName:string):Dropzone;

 emit(eventName:string, ...args:any[]):Dropzone;

 on(eventName:"drop", callback:(e:DragEvent) => any):Dropzone;
 on(eventName:"dragstart", callback:(e:DragEvent) => any):Dropzone;
 on(eventName:"dragend", callback:(e:DragEvent) => any):Dropzone;
 on(eventName:"dragenter", callback:(e:DragEvent) => any):Dropzone;
 on(eventName:"dragover", callback:(e:DragEvent) => any):Dropzone;
 on(eventName:"dragleave", callback:(e:DragEvent) => any):Dropzone;
 on(eventName:"paste", callback:(e:DragEvent) => any):Dropzone;

 on(eventName:"reset"):Dropzone;

 on(eventName:"addedfile", callback:(file:DropzoneFile) => any):Dropzone;
 on(eventName:"addedfiles", callback:(files:DropzoneFile[]) => any):Dropzone;
 on(eventName:"removedfile", callback:(file:DropzoneFile) => any):Dropzone;
 on(eventName:"thumbnail", callback:(file:DropzoneFile, dataUrl:string) => any):Dropzone;

 on(eventName:"error", callback:(file:DropzoneFile, message:string|Error) => any):Dropzone;
 on(eventName:"errormultiple", callback:(files:DropzoneFile[], message:string|Error) => any):Dropzone;

 on(eventName:"processing", callback:(file:DropzoneFile) => any):Dropzone;
 on(eventName:"processingmultiple", callback:(files:DropzoneFile[]) => any):Dropzone;

 on(eventName:"uploadprogress", callback:(file:DropzoneFile, progress:number, bytesSent:number) => any):Dropzone;
 on(eventName:"totaluploadprogress", callback:(totalProgress:number, totalBytes:number, totalBytesSent:number) => any):Dropzone;

 on(eventName:"sending", callback:(file:DropzoneFile, xhr:XMLHttpRequest, formData:FormData) => any):Dropzone;
 on(eventName:"sendingmultiple", callback:(files:DropzoneFile[], xhr:XMLHttpRequest, formData:FormData) => any):Dropzone;

 on(eventName:"success", callback:(file:DropzoneFile) => any):Dropzone;
 on(eventName:"successmultiple", callback:(files:DropzoneFile[]) => any):Dropzone;

 on(eventName:"canceled", callback:(file:DropzoneFile) => any):Dropzone;
 on(eventName:"canceledmultiple", callback:(file:DropzoneFile[]) => any):Dropzone;

 on(eventName:"complete", callback:(file:DropzoneFile) => any):Dropzone;
 on(eventName:"completemultiple", callback:(file:DropzoneFile[]) => any):Dropzone;

 on(eventName:"maxfilesexceeded", callback:(file:DropzoneFile) => any):Dropzone;
 on(eventName:"maxfilesreached", callback:(files:DropzoneFile[]) => any):Dropzone;
 on(eventName:"queuecomplete"):Dropzone;

 emit(eventName:"drop", e:DragEvent):Dropzone;
 emit(eventName:"dragstart", e:DragEvent):Dropzone;
 emit(eventName:"dragend", e:DragEvent):Dropzone;
 emit(eventName:"dragenter", e:DragEvent):Dropzone;
 emit(eventName:"dragover", e:DragEvent):Dropzone;
 emit(eventName:"dragleave", e:DragEvent):Dropzone;
 emit(eventName:"paste", e:DragEvent):Dropzone;

 emit(eventName:"reset"):Dropzone;

 emit(eventName:"addedfile", file:DropzoneFile):Dropzone;
 emit(eventName:"addedfiles", files:DropzoneFile[]):Dropzone;
 emit(eventName:"removedfile", file:DropzoneFile):Dropzone;
 emit(eventName:"thumbnail", file:DropzoneFile, dataUrl:string):Dropzone;

 emit(eventName:"error", file:DropzoneFile, message:string|Error):Dropzone;
 emit(eventName:"errormultiple", files:DropzoneFile[], message:string|Error):Dropzone;

 emit(eventName:"processing", file:DropzoneFile):Dropzone;
 emit(eventName:"processingmultiple", files:DropzoneFile[]):Dropzone;

 emit(eventName:"uploadprogress", file:DropzoneFile, progress:number, bytesSent:number):Dropzone;
 emit(eventName:"totaluploadprogress", totalProgress:number, totalBytes:number, totalBytesSent:number):Dropzone;

 emit(eventName:"sending", file:DropzoneFile, xhr:XMLHttpRequest, formData:FormData):Dropzone;
 emit(eventName:"sendingmultiple", files:DropzoneFile[], xhr:XMLHttpRequest, formData:FormData):Dropzone;

 emit(eventName:"success", file:DropzoneFile):Dropzone;
 emit(eventName:"successmultiple", files:DropzoneFile[]):Dropzone;

 emit(eventName:"canceled", file:DropzoneFile):Dropzone;
 emit(eventName:"canceledmultiple", file:DropzoneFile[]):Dropzone;

 emit(eventName:"complete", file:DropzoneFile):Dropzone;
 emit(eventName:"completemultiple", file:DropzoneFile[]):Dropzone;

 emit(eventName:"maxfilesexceeded", file:DropzoneFile):Dropzone;
 emit(eventName:"maxfilesreached", files:DropzoneFile[]):Dropzone;
 emit(eventName:"queuecomplete"):Dropzone;

}

interface JQuery {
 dropzone(options:DropzoneOptions): Dropzone;
}

declare module "dropzone" {
 export = Dropzone;
}
```

I have get Dropzone is not defined at the line "dropzone = new Dropzone(element[0], config.options);" even though I am referencing the dropzone.d.ts file at the top and it contains definitions for Dropzone.

Just to confirm the reference path is correct.

I've tried several things such as:
wrapping all of this in a :

```html
window.onload = function() {
    // access Dropzone here
};
```

as was suggested in another stackoverflow post, but then I get the error "cannot read property compile of undefined." when I put it within the registration of the directive. If I put the registration of the directive within the window.onload function then I don't get any errors but I don't think the directive gets registered, just because I put console.log in there and it wasn't printed.

```js
///<reference path="../../typings/dropzone.d.ts" />


var underscore = angular.module('underscore', []);

var app = angular.module('App', [
    'ui.router',
    'App.common',
    'App.home',
    'underscore',
    'ui.bootstrap'
]);

app.directive("dropzone", function(){
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var config, dropzone;
            config = {options: "abc"};
            // create a Dropzone for the element with the given options
            dropzone = new Dropzone(element[0], config.options);
            // bind the given event handlers
            angular.forEach(config.eventHandlers, function (handler, event) {
              dropzone.on(event, handler);
            });
    };
});
```

I feel like maybe I either need to create another module in the app.ts, which is dropzone? (Though I've tried this), or I should be doing new App.Dropzone for example? (Which I've also tried).